# Can't find the style for checkbox

Tags: java, android

I would like to programatically style my dynamically created checkboxes as radio buttons as I prefer the look.

To do this I have created a checkboxStyle.xml and put it in values section of the res folder.

*checkboxStyle.xml*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <style name="checkboxStyle">
        <item name="android:checkboxStyle">@android:style/Widget.DeviceDefault.Light.CompoundButton.RadioButton</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

I am then calling this in my fragment as I create my checkboxes but `R.id.checkboxStyle` is coming up as not found, not really sure where to put this id though or if I need to refer to it in another way

```
CheckBox checkBox;

ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
list.add("test");
list.add("this");
list.add("thing");

final ArrayList<CheckBox> checkBoxArray = new ArrayList<>();
for(int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++){
    checkBox = new CheckBox(getActivity(), null, R.id.checkboxStyle);
    checkBox.setId(i);
    checkBox.setText(list.get(i));
    checkBox.setTag(list.get(i));

    checkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            if(isChecked){
                Log.v("CheckBox - checked", buttonView.getTag().toString());
            }else{
                Log.v("CheckBox - unchecked", buttonView.getTag().toString());
            }
        }
    });

    checkBoxArray.add(checkBox);
    checkboxContainer.addView(checkBox);
}
```

*testing_layout.xml*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/colorWhite">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/checks"
        android:orientation="vertical">

    </LinearLayout>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/saveBtn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:text="Save"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Have you tried `R.style.checkboxStyle`? its not an Id, its a style!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
checkBox = new CheckBox(getActivity(), null, R.id.checkboxStyle);
```

it's not an `id`, it's an `style` and you need to access it like this

```
 R.style.checkboxStyle;
```

Comment: Seem to lose the actual checkbox/radio button bit when I run that, any ideas?

Comment: Check your xml, maybe you added custom icons for checkbox

Comment: What you see is what I have, I just drop them into a linear layout

Comment: Post your layout also, can not say anything without see what actually you are doing

Comment: See above please

Comment: You are applying Radio button style on your checkbox at runtime

Comment: Could you suggest how to get around that issue please

Comment: what you want to do

Comment: I would like to just change the check box to have the style of a radio button

Comment: just download the icons from google as you want and apply as button on your checkbox